# Python won't recognise attribute

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I am coding my first GUI application to find products for a company.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def debug():
    buttonText = relStatus.get()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("You Clicked ", buttonText)
    return

app = Tk()
app.title("Ironcraft Product Finder")
app.geometry("700x500")

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set("Choose an Appliance Type")
topLabel = Label(app, textvariable = labelText, height = 5).pack()

fire = Button(app, text="Fire", width=20, command=debug)
fire.pack(padx=10)

relStatus = StringVar()
relStatus.set(fire.text)

app.mainloop()
```

When I run this, it comes up with the error message:

```
AttributeError: Button instance has no attribute 'text'
```

But in the creation of 'fire' it says

```
text="fire"
```

Isn't this an attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tkinter module is a little old-skool; the `text` value can be accessed via an item lookup:

```
relStatus.set(fire['text'])
```

See the [Setting Options section](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html#setting-options) of the Tkinter documentation.

Comment: Thanks, never would have got that on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

```
topLabel = Label(app, textvariable = labelText, height = 5).pack()  # so topLabel is None

topLabel = Label(app, textvariable = labelText, height = 5)
topLabel.pack() # topLabel is Label
```